# Integrating "Phone Calls" and "SMS" with Google Voice

Tags: 16.04, notification

Recently (after a fun excursion with apt and the asterisk), a couple new menu items appeared in my Messages menu:

[image]

Namely, the "Phone Calls" and "SMS" options.

Now, these (just as they are) are pretty useless to me. I click on them, nothing happens. What would be cool, however, is if these integrated with Google Voice and Hangouts. Therefore, if I received a text, I'd get a new SMS, or I'd be able to respond to calls in such a way that it's integrated fully with the Ubuntu desktop.

Is such a thing possible? I'd assume as there is something called a "telephony service" that occasionally appears below these two options, there's some way to hook into it.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a laptop with no WWAN equipment inside it.

Comment: These are supposed to be used on a device with phone capabilities. you probably installed some of Ubuntu touch packages, etc.